# swiftmailer dynamic attach Symfony

Tags: php, html, symfony, sonata-admin, swiftmailer

I have a small question I try to create a template that allows to print a standard letter with inside the client information. I have already done a batch action to send emails that work but when I try to send this mail it does not work there must be a problem on the side of the attachment. I currently use Sonata Admin on Symphony 3.3. So at the reception of this mail we can open the attachment html and then print the said page html. Do you think it can work? What to do to make it work? Is this solution viable? I do not see any other ....
You can find my code there :

ClientAdmin.php :

```
public function configureBatchActions($actions)
{
if (
    $this->hasRoute('edit') && $this->hasAccess('edit') &&
    $this->hasRoute('delete') && $this->hasAccess('delete')
) {
    $actions['send_mail'] = [
        'label' => 'Send E-mail',
        'ask_confirmation' => true
    ];
}

{
$actions['send_letter'] = [
    'label' => 'Send Letter',
    'ask_confirmation' => true
];
}

return $actions;
```

ClientAdminController.php :

```
class ClientAdminController extends BaseController
{


public function batchActionSendLetter(ProxyQueryInterface $query)
{
    $this->admin->checkAccess('batchDelete');

    try {
        $clients = $query->execute();

        $this->sendLetter($clients);

        $this->addFlash('sonata_flash_success', 'E-mail send');
    } catch (ModelManagerException $e) {
        $this->handleModelManagerException($e);
        $this->addFlash('sonata_flash_error', 'Error');
    }

    return new RedirectResponse($this->admin->generateUrl(
        'list',
        ['filter' => $this->admin->getFilterParameters()]
    ));
}

public function sendLetter($clients)
{


    foreach ($clients as $client) {
        $data = \Swift_Attachment::fromPath('attach.html.twig', 'application/html');
}
        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject("Test")
            ->setFrom(' mymail')
            ->setTo('mymail@')
            ->setBody(
                $this->renderView('sendmail.html.twig',
                    array('client' => $client)),
                'text/html');
        $message->attach($data);

        $this->get('mailer')->send($message);


    return $this->redirect('/admin/dashboard');

}

}
```

service.yml :

```
admin.clients:
    class: AppBundle\Admin\ClientAdmin
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm,group : Register, label: Clients, show_mosaic_button: false}
    arguments:
        - ~
        - AppBundle\Entity\Client
        - AppBundle:ClientAdmin
    calls:
        - [ setTemplate, ['edit', "print.html.twig"]]
```

attach.html.twig :

```
<script>
var win = window.open();
var output = '';
var print = function() {
        output =
            '<div> Dear ' +
            'this is a letter to you.<br/>' +
            'Yours sincerely, .... '+
            '{{ client.surmane }} <br/>' +
            '{{ client.address }}</div>'+
            '<div style="page-break-after:always"></div>';
    win.document.write(output);
}
print();
```

So there the main problem is in the controller, in the fucntion sendletter. I have to concatenate html file in `$data` but I don't know how to do it.
Thanks in advance, if you need anything else ask I will try to give it to you

Comment: did it work if you remove the attachment?

Comment: Yes it's working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check SwiftMailer documentation : [Attaching Dynamic Content](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/messages.html#attaching-dynamic-content)

I think you have to render the file "attach.html.twig" and use the content in Swift_Attachment :

```
public function sendLetter($clients)
{
    foreach ($clients as $client) {
        $htmlContent = $this->renderView('attach.html.twig', array('clicent' => $client);
        $data = \Swift_Attachment::fromPath($htmlContent, 'letter.html', 'application/html');
        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject("Test")
            ->setFrom(' mymail')
            ->setTo('mymail@')
            ->setBody(
                $this->renderView('sendmail.html.twig',
                    array('client' => $client)),
                'text/html');
        $message->attach($data);

        $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
    }

    return $this->redirect('/admin/dashboard');

}
```

Comment: Yes of course but the main problem is that I want to send a single attachment, then to be able to display it and print it. So I would have to be able to concatenate html files in a single html file. I thought of a method to convert an html file to string all concatenate in the same variable then convert it back into an html file and send it as an attachment. But I do not know how to do that. The purpose of this script is to create printable letters containing customer information.

Comment: Il faudrait donc réussir dans le foreach seulement concaténer les fichiers html contenant la lettre imprimable ( avec les informations clients dedans ) et ensuite envoyer un seul mail contenant ce fichier html.

Comment: And what about sending $clients var to your attach.html.twig and loop into the template rather than in the controller ?

Comment: Because the template won't be able to create html lines, the idea was like : I wanna send a letter to 100 persons i select in the list this persons and when I press the bouton send letter, the script will generate a html file corresponding to each client and when the script is finish you send one big html file containing the 100 letters one after the other, and using <div style =" page-break-after: always "> </ div> 'when I press print when opening the html page 100 individualized letters. 
I hope this is understandable

Comment: And another thing when i try your solution I don't received any mail. Like with the other solution I don't know why but when I don't use the attachement it's working fine ...

Comment: An other solution is maybe to download this html file rather than sending it. Will be easier and safer cause your e-mail can be block by the anti-spam service of your email box. Have a look there http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-file-controller-helper , but what i don't know is how to contatenate this html file in one file.

Answer (score 1):

So I maybe found a solution, when you said you can create and download instead of sending it by e-mail I think about downloading the list in .xml and then using the script between excel and word to use excel data in a word. You can find the doc [there](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Mail-merge-using-an-Excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3). This is not the best solution but it's still a solution. I am still waiting for a best one if anyone have an idea.